# How to get a PHP variable value from another PHP file?

Tags: php, variables, scope

how to take the value from another .php file help me fix this:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form name='answer' action="file2.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="what">
        <input type="submit" value="Login">
    </form>
    <div><?php echo $answer; ?></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the code of file2.php file is as below:

```
<?php
    if ($_POST['what']==animal){
    $answer="dog";
}else{
    $answer= "not animal";
}
```

I would like to know how can I get the value of the variable $answer with button, then what should I put at the line :

Comment: create a readonly hidden variable. Add the value of $answer and post along with the form.

Comment: Just include the file and you can access all the variables in it `include "file2.php"`

Comment: You should include the other php file but be careful with variable names so it won't conflict with the main file, also $_post should be $_POST.

Comment: FYI, because of a variable name typo, `not animal` will never be echoed.

Comment: i fix that typo, then what should i do to get that value without go to file2.php page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use requiere

```
<?php require 'file2.php'; ?>
```

Comment: This is a low-quality answer because it doesn't say where to put the line (anything at all actually).  It doesn't say to replace the current code or anything.

Comment: where i put that code coz i use the button to get the value from file2.php without go to file2.php page?

Comment: Ok, then integrate the php code in the form and change file2.php to action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"

Answer (score 1):

Use `require_once()` to include file2.php in your php file, then in your file you can access the variables in file2.php.

```
require_once("path of file2.php");

echo $answer;
```

Comment: can you give me the example "path of file2.php"?

Comment: if your file2.php and the file1.php is in the same dir, then path of file2.php is "./file2.php" or "file2.php". You also  can give it the absolute path of file2.php.

Comment: i cant use that for the button, can you share where i place that code?

Comment: add this <?php require_once("path of file2.php"); ?> to your file1.php. I cannot do any more, you need do your homework.

Comment: i know your mean sir thanks, but what i ask its get that value without go to page file2.php, sory bad english